# how to bind event in tooltip of Highchart pie chart without disturbing Content security policy

Tags: angular, highcharts, content-security-policy

Need to bind event within highchart tooltip. I have provided some HTML snippet under High chart -> tooltip -> formatter like this -
[image]
This works fine with CSP tag- "Unsafe-inline" which is not recommended. Without CSP tag, it gives following error
[image]

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Content Security Policy gives you four options for inline script code:

1. Use 'unsafe-inline': Will allow this script, but also all other scripts including XSS
2. Use a nonce: Not available to attributes, only works on script/style tags.
3. Use the hash of the script (include 'unsafe-hashes' if used on inline event attributes): Your script is dynamic due to item.companyId and you would need hashes for all companyIds.
4. Move your script to a separate .js file loaded from an allowed location.

Your best option is to go with option 4. Use addEventListener('click', someFunction) on the element and let someFunction() method read a property containing the companyId.

You could also use option 3 if you make the code static by moving item.companyId into another property that the script can access.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onclick` attribute to allowed AST attributes as following:

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onclick');
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-avclsa

**More about Highcharts Security:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/security